# HTML table to C# DataTable using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to get a c# DataTable object from a HTML code  element and i heard that the HtmlAgilityPack can help me with it.
Is anybody familiar with this package and knows how to get a 
Datatable object from the  element?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi, may you read [ask], and [mcve]. That's the general guide line you need for using Stackoverflow. Now for your subject, [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) has clear example and documentation. So the answer is yes its possible it's quite easy.